# SuckerFish DropMenu Hides under web content

Tags: css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, z-index, suckerfish

Drop Down menu hides under the web content, I tried to resolve the issue by making changes to z-index but no luck.

This issue is with IE only. 
Please advise.

Here is link of my website

Comment: Works fine for me. What page?

Comment: Every page in IE, dropdown menu hides under content of webpage.
"Career" and "Services" has drop down menu.

Comment: I thinks its a difficult issue.